# how to test a Python class that requires command line argument?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a python class that requires a command line argument:

```
class SomeClass:
    
    request = sys.argv[1] + ".json"
    
    def __init__(self_:
       self.req = request
```

i'd run someClass.py on the commandline i.e. python someClass 1234, which would set the json to 1234.json.

I want a second class, testClass.py, to be able to test methods inside of the main class. But first, i just want to make sure its connected by printing variables:

```
from someClass import  SomeClass

i = SomeClass()

print(i.req)
```

if i run python testClass.py (without any input), i get a missing input error,

```
error: the following arguments are required: input
```

so if i run python testClass.py 1234, i get

```
none
```

i just want to know how to pull the class in and make sure its provided with an argument so i can test individual components inside of it.

Comment: Can't you build someClass so that the constructor gets an argument that you can fill in with sys.argv?

Answer (score 1):

Just overwrite `request` in every test that needs it:

```py
import unittest
from x import SomeClass

class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        SomeClass.request = ''
```

In general, don't make classes which set themselves up. Make the class take parameters which are not defaulted.

You can always make higher level code which supplies default values.

Comment: If `sys.argv[1]` doesn't exist, this will raise an `IndexError` immediately upon trying to import `x`, before you have a chance to patch `SomeClass.request`.

Comment: Yeah, another reason to not do that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make your class depend on `sys.argv` in the first place.

```
class SomeClass:        
    def __init__(self, base):
       self.req = base + ".json"
```

Then

```
from someClass import  SomeClass

i = SomeClass(sys.argv[1])  # or any other value

print(i.req)
```

Comment: Its a requirement for the deliverable, set by a requirement analyst. Wish i could change it ! Any other ideas?

Comment: You can examine the value of `sys.argv` before you import `SomeClass`, and assign to it manually if necessary. Your error message suggests that something like `argparse` is trying and failing to parse the arguments as well.